# Dual boot question

Tags: grub2, 18.04

I know this has been asked many times, but I can't find a straight answer.

I have 2 SSD installed on my computer, /dev/sda and /dev/sdb, I ran dd to create a clone of /dev/sda into /dev/sdb, but when I restart the computer it starts using /boot from /dev/sda1 and the / folder from /dev/sdb2 and I don't want that, I want when it starts with /dev/sda to use only sda and when starting with sdb to use only sdb, I tried running update-grub, but I get nowhere with it, what can I do to fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: If you remove sdb, will the PC boot OK from sda,, and vice versa?

Answer (score 1):

When you use dd to copy the 2 SSD's, it copy everything, including the partition and the ext4 UID. When booting up /dev/sda1, it tries to mount the root filesytem that matches with the configured UID. It just so happens that it found it on /dev/sdb2 and hence started using it instead of /dev/sda2.

To fix this, you will need to regenerate the UID for /dev/sdb2

```
sudo tune2fs -U random /dev/sdb2
```

If you need the grub bootloader to use /dev/sdb2 when booting from /dev/sdb1, you will need to update the grub setting in /dev/sdb1 to look for the new UID you have just generated.

Edited: Some additional info. You can quickly check the UUID using the `blkid` command.

```
blkid
```

Note that changing UUID requires files system is clean, so it may not be possible to update a mounted filesystem.

Comment: I did that but /dev/sdb2 still shows the same UUID of /dev/sda2

Comment: Ah sorry, I got the uuid mxed up, may be the random doesn't do it. I'll add instruction to use uuid generator.

Comment: Deleted: saw your post, glad you have your problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

Never mind, I did using:

```
uuidgen
tune2fs -U '<uuid generated>' /dev/sdb2
```

And it shows now with a different UUID, GRUB2 has been customized using grub-customizer and triple checked that the UUIDs of the 2 boot drives were different.

Thanks for the suggestion though, it was very helpful.

Comment: Great! I learn something new from this. thanks.